# Custom hardware causing Linux boot to hang after initrd on PC

Tags: hardware, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci

We've created some custom hardware that uses PCIe 2.0. This hardware works with an HP DL360 G7 server with CentOS Linux 5.4. So on the HP server Linux is able to cold-boot just fine, recognize the card, and interface with our driver. However, when we try plugging the card into a regular Dell T3500 PC Linux is unable to boot. It hangs after initrd with no crash, debug, or error messages. So my question is, what tools or settings are available to help debug this problem? We want to know why the boot process can't get past initrd.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live CD such as Knoppix and use the utilities available to you there to diagnose the problem (dmesg, dconf, lspci, etc).  It could very well be that there are conflicts between your driver and hardware that's on the Dell.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from your description if the boot is hanging while mounting initrd or if its hanging while executing the contents in the initrd (init scripts, etc). If the latter,I've diagnosed similar problems by cracking open the initrd and altering the init scripts inside it to just immediately drop to a bash prompt. Then re-archive the initrd, and you should boot right to a prompt. From there you can manually execute each command in the initrd init scripts until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

The KGDB kernel debugger allows you to connect the failing machine to another over a serial port, and use `gdb` on the second machine to debug the kernel on the first.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the related dell drivers

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/ -name "*dell*"
```

do a `tar -cf` to back them up, then delete all these ko files.